# com.google.gson.JsonPrimitive cannot be cast to com.google.gson.JsonObject ERROR

Tags: exception, gson, classcastexception

When i try to parjse the json object from thelist i get an error com.google.gson.JsonPrimitive cannot be cast to com.google.gson.JsonObject

Input:

```
{
    "r$contentRatings": [
        {
            "r$scheme": "urn:rt",
            "r$rating": "criticSummaryScore=-1,criticSummaryCount=0,criticSummaryCertified=false,criticSummaryRotten=false,fanSummaryScore=75,fanSummaryCount=4"
        }
    ]
}
```

Code:

```
JsonElement elem = null;
elem = jsonObject.get("r$contentRatings");

if(elem != null) {
    JsonArray contentRatingsList = elem.getAsJsonArray();
    if(contentRatingsList != null) {                                                                                                    
        for(int i=0; i< contentRatingsList.size(); i++) {
            JsonObject scheme =contentRatingsList.get(i).getAsJsonObject().getAsJsonObject("r$scheme");
            JsonObject rating =contentRatingsList.get(i).getAsJsonObject().getAsJsonObject("r$rating");
            JsonArray subRatings = contentRatingsList.get(i).getAsJsonObject().getAsJsonObject("r$subRatings").getAsJsonArray();
```

Error:

Inside the for loop, when i try to access the `jsonobject` from the list `r$scheme` I get an error

> com.google.gson.JsonPrimitive cannot be cast to com.google.gson.JsonObject

Can you please let me know how to get rid of this error..

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Simply, in your json

```
{
    "r$contentRatings": [
        {
            "r$scheme": "urn:rt",
            "r$rating": "criticSummaryScore=-1,criticSummaryCount=0,criticSummaryCertified=false,criticSummaryRotten=false,fanSummaryScore=75,fanSummaryCount=4"
        }
    ]
}
```

The elements `r$scheme` and `r$rating` are not json objects, but json primitives.

Use

```
JsonPrimitive scheme = contentRatingsList.get(i).getAsJsonObject().getAsJsonPrimitive("r$scheme");
JsonPrimitive rating = contentRatingsList.get(i).getAsJsonObject().getAsJsonPrimitive("r$rating");
```

Also, note that you have no element named `r$subRatings` in your json so you are setting yourself up for a `NullPointerException` in the next line.